# Teams Bot installed through Global policy is blocked only for some users and cannot unblock

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have installed a Bot via manifest file in the Microsoft Teams to all the users in the organization. While most of the users have Bot delivering messages but some users have the Bot conversation/Bot blocked automatically. The messages are delivered to the Teams Bot by our application and receiving the following response to only some users: `com.microsoft.bot.connector.rest.ErrorResponseException: Status code 403, {"error":{"code":"ConversationBlockedByUser","message":"User blocked the conversation with the bot."}}`

We have tried to unblock manually by hovering over the Bot in the chat section-> clicking on the ... -> click unblock but no change. Also, tried different ways to unblock the bot on Teams app but does no change. The Bot is installed to all the users with the same policy from the Teams Admin center so we are unsure what the issue might be..

Comment: have you maintained any other policy for blocked users?

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth: Verified and see that all the users have default allowed all policy. The strange part is that the bot actually delivered one message and then it probably got blocked for at least one user.

Comment: did you get any updates from Microsoft?

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth : We are still in middle of understanding the issue. I will update back once I get more details from MSFT. Please feel free to post any solutions I can try ..

Comment: What did MS say in the end?

Comment: I don't recall MS having a answer why this happened. They checked the logs on their end and everything looked fine from their side. The solution was to have the users unblock themselves which was not useful in our case.